# Sonicwall tz210 WAN not receiving dhcp address

Tags: sonicwall, wide-area-network

I have a SonicWall TZ210 running SonicROM 5.0.2.11.  There are two ISPs: ISP A gives a static address and is currently working fine.  ISP B offers a cable modem and a DHCP address.  The TZ210 connects successfully through ISP A with the static address, but I can't get the TZ210 to receive an address from ISP B.

I have ISB B connected to the X6 port. X6 is in the WAN Zone and set to DHCP but no other configurations have been set.  The status for that port shows 100Mbps full-duplex so layer 1 looks solid.  I've added X6 to the Load Balance group and removed it with no change.

What steps am I missing to get DHCP working on the X6 WAN Port?

Comment: Have you considered that maybe for some reason the ISP B is not leasing addresses? Try connecting another device with DHCP enabled in the ISP B.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't add that to my OP.  I've connected a Linksys E1000 running DD-WRT and directly connected a Macbook Pro, both receive a DHCP address.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but most likely your ISP only allows so many DHCP leases which were all exhausted from the other router and the MacBook. The default lease time on DHCP is typically 8 days. Once one of the leases expired, your SonicWALL was able to obtain a lease which is why "after about a week" it started working.

Hopefully this will at least clear any doubt that there is/was something wrong with your device.

Also, you may have been able to clear this up faster by performing a DHCP release from one of the devices that had obtained an address via DHCP. That will signal to your ISP that you no longer need the lease and free it up.

Answer (score 0):

After about a week the port picked up an address through DHCP and is functioning properly, no configuration changes.